# Fail to write model history to a json file in the end of 2nd epoch of a keras fit_generator training

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using a customized callback to save model history parameters (loss, acc, etc.) to a json file on_epoch_end. I used a keras fit_generator to train the data. In the end of 1st epoch, everything works fine and i can get the json file with parameters. However, after 2nd epoch, i always encounter an long error ending with "TypeError: Object of type 'float32' is not JSON serializable". I am very confused, because the model history is a dictionary.

I have tried:
1) change json.dumps to json.dump. But the same error in the end of 2nd epoch
2) I have commented out json file portion, and add a code "print(self.H)" in my callback class. It works. By every end of epoch, the model history dictionary can be printed out and my training can be completed without error.
3) I use lr decay. One observation is that there is no "lr" parameter in the model history dictionary for the 1st epoch, and a "lr" parameter will be added since 2nd epoch onwards for the history dictionary.

```
class TrainingMonitor(BaseLogger):
    def __init__(self, figPath, jsonPath=None, startAt=0):
        # store the output path for the figure, the path to the JSON
        # serialized file, and the starting epoch
        super(TrainingMonitor, self).__init__()
        self.figPath = figPath
        self.jsonPath = jsonPath
        self.startAt = startAt

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        # initialize the history dictionary
        self.H = {}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # loop over the logs and update the loss, accuracy, etc.
        # for the entire training process
        for (k, v) in logs.items():
            l = self.H.get(k, [])
            l.append(v)
            self.H[k] = l

        # check to see if the training history should be serialized to the file
        if self.jsonPath is not None:
            f = open(self.jsonPath, "w")
            f.write(json.dumps(self.H))
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by changing "l.append(v)" to "l.append(float(v))". The error is because that data type of "lr" is numpy.float32 and json's encoder might not be able to encode it. Below shows data type has been changed to native Python float type then no problem to be written into json.

```
acc <class 'numpy.float64'>

acc <class 'float'>

lr <class 'numpy.float32'>

lr <class 'float'>
```